# Why "Uncaught ReferenceError: populateDetailsForEditForm is not defined" is coming @ frontend?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-modal

This code is in one of my JS file, `gatewayList.js`. In this file I have the following function:

```
function loadDetailsForEdit(data){
    editGatewayDialog = BootstrapDialog.show({
        title: 'Edit Gateway',
        cssClass: 'modified-dialog',
        closeByBackdrop: false,
        closeByKeyboard: false,
        onshow: function(dialog) {
            populateDetailsForEditForm(data);
        },
        message: $('<div></div>').load(EDIT_FORM),
    });
}
```

The above function calls `populateDetailsForEditForm(data)`.
This function is defined in another JS file, whose name is `editGateway.js`

```
function populateDetailsForEditForm(gateway) {
    $('#editForm').show();
    $('#remarks').val(gateway.remarks);
}
```

But server can not find this `editGateway.js` file from `gatewayList.js` file. it's giving this following error in the chrome browser:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: populateDetailsForEditForm is not defined

**list.html**

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row"> 
    <div class="col-xs-12 dataGridTitle">
      Recent Gateway List
    </div> 
    <div class="col-xs-12" style="border: 1px solid #ADADAD; padding-top:10px"> 
      <table id="gatewayGrid" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%"> 
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Gateway Id</th> 
            <th>Gateway Name</th> 
            <th>Issuing Country</th>
          </tr> 
        </thead>
      </table>
    </div> 
  </div> 
</div> 
<script src="/administration/gateway/controller/editGateway.js"></sc‌​ript> 
<script src="/administration/gateway/controller/gatewayList.js"></sc‌​ript>
```

Comment: have you included both `edit.js` and `list.js` on your "frontend". Are they in the correct order?

Comment: it's actually populateDetailsForEditForm.

Comment: populateGatewayEditForm(data) this is decleared in list.js
and defined in edit.js
and both these 2 files are in same folder

Comment: yes it's need to be place in the different files because the data is populated from the controller to edit.js

Comment: There are 2 html files also: edit.html and list.html.
I have called list.js in list.html where populateDetailsForEditFrom(data) is decleared and it's defined in edit.js which is called in edit.html. This edit.html is also loaded in list.js through bootstrap dialog

Comment: yeah theres your problem. If you want to access something from `edit.js` in your `list.html` then you need to include it in `list.html`

Comment: I have already done that but it's still showing the same error

Comment: `edit.js` needs to come before `list.js`. can you share the code for `list.html`

Comment: thanks  Craicerjack. Problem solved. You Rockz

Comment: Glad that you got it sorted.